# How can I have characters have very little to no communications with outside world without it sounding too contrived?

Tags: narrative, science-fiction

This will be like 1 of 3 posts about this story.

I am writing (or plan to at least) a story about these folks that are shrunk and sent out to make 'first' contact with a civilization of cockroaches. Things go...less than great...twice.

How can I write a convincing reason for two groups of people (like 35 people in all) not having the comms to contact help?

For a bit more context, this takes place around 2016-202x in the US. Also stuff on them and nonliving things can be shrunk.

Comment: This is probably 'asking what to write', which is off-topic on this exchange. We can't write your plot for you.... I suggest you think about the THEME of your story (science hubris?) and figure out a reason that re-enforces that theme.... (or just blame it on the protagonist somehow to create extra conflict for them).

Comment: No, not asking for plot material, this is asking how I should 'weave' it. I had plan originally that the most of the 1st group of people got killed off before they could call for help or were too shocked to do so and the lone survivor's phone died before he could call, kinda the same for the 2nd group, but I think a few just did not bring them. This does not account for radios, assuming they had them. I feel this could seem too contrived, so I thought I would ask for advice on what to do@wetcircuit

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com, if you want to figure out the technical aspects of (the failure of) shrunk-to-non-shrunk communication.

Comment: If people are shrunk there are all kinds of reasons they might not be able to use communication devices - they can hardly just operate a computer or phone. But it's going to require a lot of thought and world-building (e.g. why wouldn't they have shrunken comms devices with them?) Some works solve this by requiring that only organic matter can be shrunk (or teleported, sent through time, etc).